# Get authenticated user's groups from Active Directory in Node

Tags: node.js, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

We were asked to move our NodeJS app to run under IIS (Windows Server 2012R2) and integrate with an existing Active Directory. We were requested to remove the login page, and instead use Windows Authentication to get the (already authenticated) user's ID, and the use the groups he/she belongs to, to control their authorization level within the app.

I've installed [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) to run my app under IIS, and figured I'll use either [passport-windowsauth](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth), or [node-activedirectory](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory) to get the group memebership. However, both require user/password to authenticate the user. My user is **already authenticated**, and I have no access to his password (nor should I).

How do I go about getting an authenticated user's groups from Active Directory?

**Here's what I have so far:**

1. Installed and configured  iisnode
2. Enabled Windows Authentication for the web app
3. Added this to web.config: `<iisnode promoteServerVars="AUTH_USER,AUTH_TYPE" />`
4. In my `index.js` file, I can then `console.log(req.headers['x-iisnode-auth_user']);` and get the correct user name - but I don't know how to proceed from here to getting his/her groups
5. Under no circumstances do I want to re-ask the user for his/her password

Comment: hey, how to get the details of already authenticated user info in the nodejs app? case1: node js app is hosted on windows server case 2: nodejs app is not hosted on windows server\

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, seems like no one is interested in looking at this question :). I'm assuming IIS + Node.js + Active Directory is an edge case. 
Here's how I ended up solving this one:

1. Add a special user to the Active Directory that can only be logged into from the IIS machine (bonus: limit the IP/process/access of that user).
2. Add the AD details, user name, and password to `config.json` file (see [snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/17213)).
   Make sure you add the file to `.gitignore` so it won't end up in repo.
3. Use [node-ActiveDirectory](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory) to first sign in as the user from step 1, and then ask for the groups of the logged in user (see [snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/17212)).