# nodejs ntlm get a user's groups

Tags: node.js, express, active-directory, ntlm, express-ntlm

I am using [express-ntlm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ntlm). The authentication with the domain controller is working fine. But I need to get authenticated user's group details. Actually a particular group will be authorised.

I found some examples [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622797/active-directory-authentication-with-nodejs)[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341909/get-authenticated-users-groups-from-active-directory-in-node)

But it seems using [node-activedirectory](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory) I need to know user's password. But can I do it without using user's password? Or is there anyway to get password from ntml?

Answer (score 0):

No, NTLM never provides passwords. Its just a way of User authentication using 3 way handshaking inside a corporate network.